# Does shallow copy work as deep copy in case of immutable objects in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am reading java concurrency in practice. I came across this snippet which is causing me some confusion.
**If an unchanging view of the fleet is required, getLocations could instead return a shallow copy of the locations map. Since the contents of the Map are immutable, only the structure of the Map, and not the contents must be copied.**

```java
public Map<String,Point> getLocations(){
 return Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String,Point>(locations));
}
```

**To return an unmodifiable but live view of the vehicle locations**.

```java
public Map<String,Point> getLocations(){
return unmodifiableMap; //unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(locations);
}
```

```java
public class Point{
 public final int x,y;
 public Point(int x, int y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y=y;
 }
}
```

```java
public void setLocation(String id,int x,int y){
 if(locations.replace(id,new Point(x,y==null)
   //throw exception for invalid vehicle
}
```

Does this imply that `new HashMap<String,Point>(locations)` is doing a deep copy of the locations map and assigning a new reference by creating a new object for Point when the copy is happening. Shouldn't shallow copy `new HashMap<String,Point>(locations)` retain the original reference to Point objects, and the change be visible in all threads.

Comment: Why do you think it performs deep copy? I think the point here is that with immutable objects, copying just the references and not the objects themselves is good enough.

Comment: but why does it state the change wont be visible in other threads ?

Comment: Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String,Point>(locations)); vs unmodifiableMap;
my confusion lies here. For first change not visible in other threads, for second it would be

Comment: Where does it talk about the change being visible to other threads? All it says is - do you want a copy of the current state of the map (which means future changes shouldn't affect this copy) or a view of the map that reflects future changes in it (which means it is backed by the real map)?

Comment: (That `Point` class should be `final`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a deep copy because the Point objects are immutable and cannot change. This is asserted in:

> Since the contents of the Map are immutable

If the Point objects were mutable you would in deed have to make a deep copy.

The difference between the two implementations if getLocations refers to visibility to changes in the "structure" of the map. The first implementation returns an unmodifiable view **of a copy** of the map. If locations are added or removed after the method returns, it will not be visible in the map returned by this method. The second returns an unmodifiable view of the map itself. Any changes made after the method returns will be visible to the caller.

Comment: Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String,Point>(locations)); vs unmodifiableMap;
my confusion lies here. For first, change not visible in other threads, for second it would be

Comment: for the first case i believe i understand what you are saying. since setlocation is using a new reference to point each time it is called and map from get locations must be pointing to old reference is not changed, we dont get to see updated value.
but I am not getting why is the same thing not happening for collections.unmodifiablemap, when it is also just a copy of the original map locations. does collections.unmodifiablemap point to same address as the original map ?

Comment: Collections.unmodifiablemap is not a copy of the map locations, it's an "unmodifiable view." It doesn't create a copy, instead it calls methods in the map you pass to it.

Comment: thanks a lot, it clears things up now. thanks for the help